# jQuery $.Get not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with $.get that I've never had before, and can't seem to be able to fix it. When calling the following function:

```
function getDefinition (word) {
var toget = "http://www.stands4.com/services/v1/defs.aspx?tokenid=TOKEN&word=" + word;
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.get(toget, function (data) {
    if(data.indexOf("<definition>") !== -1)
    {
        var definition = data.split("<definition>")[1].split("</definition>")[0];
        return definition;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

}

Internet Explorer (I've not tested it on other browsers) throws

> "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf' 
>   randomfunctions.js, line 5 character 3" (line 5 character 3 would be
>   the "i" in "if")

Earlier I was getting a CORS error, so I added the

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

line. I've attempted to alert(data), but the same thing happens. I'm using jQuery 1.6.1.

any help would be greatly appreciated,
Matthew

Comment: what's data really been return to, have you tried debug this JS to watch that, it more looks like an array data or something else

Comment: putting `alert(data); return;` as the top line of that function should tell you what it is. My guess is `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do is to set a breakpoint in the debugger right before the `.indexOf()` call and examine the `data` variable to see if it's what you're expecting and if it has that method or not.  Since we don't know what that data is, that's hard for us to say, but obviously IE is having difficulty with that.

`.indexOf()` can be a method on a string or an array.  The array version is relatively new and some older browsers (or behind the times browsers) don't yet have support for it.  If `data` was an array, that could be the issue.  If that was the case, then you can either replace `.indexOf()` with a manual search through the array or add an ES5 shim for `.indexOf()`.  There's a shim implementation of Array.indexOf() [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on mdn.

It also looks like you're trying to return your data from the success handler of the `$.get()` call.  That doesn't work.  The success function is called by the internals of the ajax engine.  Returning data to it does nothing - the data will just be dropped.

From an asynchronous ajax call (which`$.get()` is by default), you can't return your data from that suucess handler or from the `.get()` call.  The data is only available in the success handler which happens sometime later.  Instead, you must put any code that uses that data in the success handler or in a function call that gets called from the success handler.  That's how asynch ajax calls must work.  You can do traditional sequential programming with them.

Comment: @Baz1nga - I've added info on the .indexOf() issue too.  But, as soon as he gets past that, the rest of the code won't work either because of the other issue.

Comment: the problem persisted even when I commented out all the if/else code and just added an alert(data). But I found this a little surprising since I'd been using $.get() like this before. It turns out the problem was half the asyncronity and half that it was actually being returned as XML, thus jQuery decided to return it in some kind of weird array :) simply adding jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false}); before the $.get, jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:true}); after the $.get, and adding an extra parameter (, "html") to the end of the request fixed the asynchronity issues and returned the XML as I wanted it

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an older version of IE, then indexOf may not be supported:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf